# 1984 BMW 733i Trailer Attachment?

Tags: bmw, trailer

I have a 1984 BMW 733i. I am curious if it is possible to attach a trailer hitch to it for connecting a light motorcycle trailer. It seems there is no connection for it but I am not totally sure just from looking.

Comment: Curt makes one for the 84 7 series sedan....http://www.curtmfg.com/part/11515#tab=vehicles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the 'U-Haul trailer hitch' (U-haul is a US based truck rental/towing company) website to search your vehicle, and it appears nobody makes a direct bolt on trailer hitch mount for your vehicle. Custom holes and a custom bracket will need to be drilled/fabricated for the rear sub-frame of your vehicle to mount a trailer hitch. It's not impossible, but it will cost you a few hundred USD.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I figured, but I couldn't tell by just looking under the rear of the car. The U-haul trailer hitch website seems like a good resource for this.